# Automake condition in configure.ac by gcc version

Tags: gcc, makefile, configure, automake

I would like to add flags using automake to the configure.ac file so that I can change the flag package depending on the version of gcc on host.
I tried to do that:

configure.ac (I enter the following command at the top of this file)

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([gcc_v_above_4_9], [test x$(expr `gcc -dumpversion | sed -e 's/\.\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1/g' -e 's/\.\([0-9]\)/0\1/g' -e 's/^[0-9]\{3,4\}$/&00/'` \>= 40900) = x1])
```

Makefile.am

```
if gcc_v_above_4_9
    AM_CFLAGS += -fstack-protector-strong
endif
```

then I run a script ./autogen.sh (everything clear), and then ./configure and I have got a message like this:

```
configure: error: conditional "gcc_v_above_4_9" was never defined.
Usually this means the macro was only invoked conditionally.
```

What should I do to make flags dependent on the gcc version?

Comment: please post complete files. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am so sorry, but i can't do that.

Comment: Is there a particular reason not just check whether the compiler (whatever compiler and version that may be) can compile with `-fstack-protector-strong`? Also, if I really needed to check the compiler version, I would let gcc examine its internally defined macros and use the result via `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE`.

Comment: No, it is the only example. I have more flags that depending on the GCC version. I am trying to insert if loop, but always I get this error.